# Write a shell script to send S/MIME signed emails via Mutt

Tags: shell, email, mutt, smime

I'm making an app (tiny PHP website) that sends my AirBnB guest info to the police (which I'm required to do - it's what they do in a hotel, when they take your passport at check-in).

The app needs to generate a file with guest's data and then send it to the Czech police department via a digitally signed email. The first part is done but I've got stuck with Mutt for yet another day.

My goal is to send a S/mime signed email with an attachment with a shell script without any user interaction. So something like this:

```
mutt -s 'My mail ' abc@gmail.com -a report1.txt < report2.txt
```

The code above sends an email with an attachment but without a digital signature although enabled by default in muttrc.

I've managed to send signed emails with mutt but only via it's interactive shell plus I need to manually type in the password for my private key every time, the code above doesn't ask for the password just sends it without a signature straight away.

I tried generating the key with an empty PEM pass but then OpenSSL didn't like it at all and aborted immediately.

Comment: What was the command you tried to get the passwordless key?

Comment: Thank you very much! Don't remember but it was wrong, I've just generated it properly and it works with empty passphrase (inside the interactive shell) but it still doesn't sign it when I send the email with the command. Any ideas?

Comment: Here's what I have in my muttrc:
`set smime_certificates=~/.smime/certificates
set smime_keys=~/.smime/keys
source ~/.mutt/smime.rc
set smime_default_key=af7d0df7.0
set crypt_autosign=yes
set smime_is_default=yes`

Answer (score 1):

I would use sendmail command instead of mutt.

```
openssl smime -sign -in report.txt -text -signer cert.pem \
-from you@domain.com -to abc@gmail.com \
-subject "My mail" | sendmail abc@gmail.com
```

In this example, cert.pem is created from a PKCS12 file:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in yourcert.p12 -out cert.pem -clcerts -nodes
```

report.txt is the plain text file/report to be signed and sent.

The OpenSSL smime(1) man page has a few more good examples.

Comment: I've tried this too, the thing is I need to include an attachment (small text file) and I couldn't find a way to do this with sendmail :/

Answer (score 0):

Desperate people do desperate things. I edited the openssl source code to generate `Content-Type: text/plain;\r\n` instead of `Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n` so that I could follow up with:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment;
        filename="test.txt"
```